# In Viewpager how to validate form on page change and if any empty field stay back on same page?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I used ViewPager using [PagerSlidingTabStrip Library](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip.git) and forms on each page.I try to validate forms on `SimpleOnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected` method and if any field is empty return to same page again.But my following code works properly on swipe of page,but if I click on tabs,not return to previous page.In Viewpager how to validate form on page change and if any empty field stay back on same page?

```
private int mLastPage;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mLastPage = 0;

        newInspectionPagerTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.new_inspection_pager_tab_strip);
        newInspectionPagerTabStrip.setViewPager(mViewpager);

        newInspectionPagerTabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);

                NewInspectionPagerAdapter adapter = (NewInspectionPagerAdapter)mViewpager.getAdapter();

                // If reverse page navigation(page 1 to page 0) dont validate forms and return   
                if(mLastPage > position){
                    return;
                }

                // If move from Page-0 to Page-1
                if(mLastPage==0){
                    NewInspectionFragment1 newInspectionFragment1 = (NewInspectionFragment1) adapter.getRegisteredFragment(0);
                    View newInspectionForm1GridLayout = newInspectionFragment1.getView();

                    EditText timeInEditText = (EditText) newInspectionForm1GridLayout.findViewById(R.id.new_inspection_form1_et_value_timein);
                    String timeIn = timeInEditText.getText().toString();

                    FORM_1_TIMEIN = timeIn;

                    EditText ageEditText = (EditText) newInspectionForm1GridLayout.findViewById(R.id.new_inspection_form1_et_value_age);
                    int age = ageEditText.getText().toString();

                    FORM_1_AGE = age;

                    // If any field is empty, again return to Page-0 and set mLastPage as 0
                    if(FORM_1_TIMEIN.isEmpty() || FORM_1_AGE==0)
                    {
                        mViewpager.setCurrentItem(0);

                        if(FORM_1_AGE==0)
                        {
                            ageEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_age));
                            ageEditText.requestFocus();
                        }

                        if(FORM_1_TIMEIN.isEmpty())
                        {
                            timeInEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_timein));
                            timeInEditText.requestFocus();
                        }

                        mLastPage = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else if(mLastPage==1){
                    NewInspectionFragment2 newInspectionFragment2 = (NewInspectionFragment2) adapter.getRegisteredFragment(1);
                    View newInspectionForm2GridLayout = newInspectionFragment2.getView();

                    EditText totalEditText = (EditText) newInspectionForm2GridLayout.findViewById(R.id.new_inspection_form2_et_value_total);
                    int total=totalMortalityEditText.getText().toString();

                    FORM_2_TOTAL = total;

                    EditText percentageEditText = (EditText) newInspectionForm2GridLayout.findViewById(R.id.new_inspection_form2_et_value_percentage);
                    int percentage=percentageEditText.getText().toString();

                    FORM_2_PERCENTAGE = percentage;

                    if(FORM_2_TOTAL==0 || FORM_2_PERCENTAGE==0)
                    {
                        mViewpager.setCurrentItem(1);

                        if(FORM_2_PERCENTAGE==0)
                        {
                            percentageEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_percentage));
                            percentageEditText.requestFocus();
                        }

                        if(FORM_2_TOTAL_MORTALITY==0)
                        {
                            totalEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_total));
                            totalEditText.requestFocus();
                        }

                        mLastPage = 1;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else if(mLastPage==2){
                   // Do Same as above // Removed for code clarity
                }
                mLastPage = position;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: i did you got any solution for this.i also have the same  problem

Comment: I have Same Problem have you solve this isssue